# Javascript Google Earth Api - update all polygons coordinates instantly (multigeometry?)

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

I'm working on creating 3D shapes on Google Earth Api. I wanna make them move and rotate so I wrote a script to create polygons and then update their coordinates. The result is not really nice because all faces of my 3D polygons are updating slowly one after the other. You can see it in action here (you have to wait 5sec for the update):

http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/64y5Q/

```
function createPolygon(id, lati, longi, alti){

if(!gePoly[id]['placemarks'][polyCount]){
var newPoly = true;
gePoly[id]['placemarks'][polyCount] = ge.createPlacemark('');
gePoly[id]['polygons'][polyCount] = ge.createPolygon('');
gePoly[id]['polygons'][polyCount].setAltitudeMode(ge.ALTITUDE_ABSOLUTE);
gePoly[id]['placemarks'][polyCount].setGeometry(gePoly[id]['polygons'][polyCount]);
var outer = ge.createLinearRing('');
}
    for(i = 0; i < lati.length; i++){
      if(newPoly)
      outer.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lati[i], longi[i], alti[i]);
      else{
      var gOuter = gePoly[id]['placemarks'][polyCount].getGeometry().getOuterBoundary();
      gOuter.getCoordinates().setLatLngAlt(i, lati[i], longi[i], alti[i]);
      }
    }
    if(newPoly) gePoly[id]['polygons'][polyCount].setOuterBoundary(outer);

ge.getFeatures().appendChild(gePoly[id]['placemarks'][polyCount]);
polyCount++;
}
```

So, I'm looking for a way to update all polygons coordinates instantly. A strange observation I made: if during the update loading you zoom or pan the map, it will do it instantly... It proves that there is a solution, right?

I found info about Multigeometries that are a collection of geometries:
https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/geometries#multigeometry.

This collection load all geometries at the same time (exactly what I want) but it seems to work only for lines and not for polygons. If somebody knows how to make it work for polygons, it would be very appreciated to hear it from you!

Answer (score 0):

Oh my god! I finally found the solution! For the Multigeometry thing, it was pretty easy for polygons: it's basically the exact same thing as lines (I probably made a mistake somewhere the first time). That was not the solution by the way. The way to go is using the [executeBatch()](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/google_earth_namespace#a263985709518fe438a8f4d69d8a8e334) function that will do all in one move:

```
google.earth.executeBatch(ge, function(){
  for(i = 0; i < lati.length; i++){
    outer.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(lati[i], longi[i], alti[i]);
  }
});
```